# How to sort list by date within a string

Tags: python

I have the following list of strings:

```
files = ['hulu_delta_20150517.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150518.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150519.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150520.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150521.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150522.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150523.xml', 'hulu_full20150517.xml', 'hulu_full20150518.xml']
```

I want to sort it by the date within the string. How would I do that? So far I have:

```
sorted(files, key=lambda x: re.search(r'\d{8}',s).group())
```

But this just gives me the same as the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bullet-proofed this a bit more than required...

This verifies that the 8-digit string is *exactly* 8 digits, since `'001001010100'...` probably wasn't intended as a date.

It then verifies it's a *valid* date.  (Hat tip to **anmol_uppal** --- much easier than slicing up the string for `datetime.date`.)

Date strings are left as strings, since they will sort correctly.  All non-dated strings are sorted in ASCII-betical order, and show up first in the output.

```python
import re
import time

def sort_by_iso_date(strings):
    # Pre-sort in ASCII-betical order, then sort by ISO date string.
    # This makes the final order predictable without complicating the
    # key function.
    strings = sorted(strings)
    return sorted(strings, key=first_iso_date_string)


def first_iso_date_string(s):
    '''
    Returns the first string of _exactly_ 8 digits in the given
    string s, or '' if no 8-digit sequence was found.
    '''
    date_regex = r'''
      (?<!\d)          # Not preceded by a digit.
      (?P<date>\d{8})  # Match _exactly_ 8 digits.  Name the group 'date'.
      (?!\d)           # Not followed by a digit.
    '''
    pattern = re.compile(date_regex, re.X)
    match = re.search(pattern, s)
    no_date_found = ''
    if match is None:
        return no_date_found
    iso_date_string = match.group('date')
    if not is_valid_date(iso_date_string):
        return no_date_found
    return iso_date_string


def is_valid_date(yyyymmdd):
    try:
        __ = time.strptime(yyyymmdd, '%Y%m%d')
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your variable names are correct, it should be `x` and not `s` for the lambda expression:

```
>>> sorted(files, key=lambda x: re.search(r'\d{8}',x).group())
['hulu_delta_20150517.xml', 'hulu_full20150517.xml', 
 'hulu_delta_20150518.xml', 'hulu_full20150518.xml', 
 'hulu_delta_20150519.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150520.xml', 
 'hulu_delta_20150521.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150522.xml',
 'hulu_delta_20150523.xml']
```

Comment: It will work, since the dates are in YYYYMMDD format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort by converting the string to a `struct_time` object and then sorting over that object.

```
import time

files = ['hulu_delta_20150517.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150518.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150519.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150520.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150521.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150522.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150523.xml', 'hulu_full20150517.xml', 'hulu_full20150518.xml']

a = time.strptime("20150517", "%Y%m%d")

b = sorted(files, key = lambda x:time.strptime(x[-12:-4], "%Y%m%d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the elegant one but gave a try.

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter
files = ['hulu_delta_20150517.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150518.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150519.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150520.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150521.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150522.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150523.xml', 'hulu_full20150517.xml', 'hulu_full20150518.xml']
num=[re.findall('\d+', i)[0] for i in files]
print [elem[0] for elem in sorted(list(zip(files,num)),key=itemgetter(1))]
```

Output

```
['hulu_delta_20150517.xml', 'hulu_full20150517.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150518.xml', 'hulu_full20150518.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150519.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150520.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150521.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150522.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150523.xml']
```